# Tilting when chip is growing?

Tags: texas-hold-em, bankroll-management

so this is happening quite frequently that I've set a hard rule. get up after 100 hands.

but after 100 hands, im up 12x buy in. giddy and excited i keep bullying and folding.

I have no problem getting chips, I seem to have issue with KEEPING IT and not getting into every pot because the gambling side of me starts to take over.

I looked everywhere but most of the tilting they talk about is when you play like shit but mine is almost when i achieve 3~20x the buy in money, I stick around to see if I can get more and I ALWAYS END UP LOSING IT ALL.

TLDR: 0.02/0.05 NLH

I turned my 2.50 into $25 and lost it all in 200 hands in zoom poker. How do I fix and manage my emotions when im winning?

Comment: I did not downvote, but your "question" doesn't actually ask a question. It's just you describing what's going on for you. Stack Exchange is not a forum where people have discussions. It's strictly for  questions and answers. Please [edit] your question such that it's actually a question. This doesn't mean that this couldn't be a good question for the site, just that it's not currently a asking anything.

Comment: oh okay, i edited the question to include a question. how do i manage this tilt....that happens when my stack has multiplied? basically i get excited and then all the discipline goes out the window....it happening consistently

Comment: Are you drinking or using drugs when you play?

Comment: @paparazzo yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to one of the hardest things for me to learn in poker, discipline. It is important to play based on the amount of big blinds you have, rather than the amount of money you have. It is common for players (including me) to think that they can loosen up (often too much) when they are winning.

Just remember that you can lose just as fast as you can win. The important thing is to make the best decision as frequently as possible. discipline takes practice and it is good that you are practicing it at the micro stakes.

Answer (score 1):

Theres quite abit of information missing in your post, but two things come to mind, none of which are related to tilt.

1 - Risk of ruin: If you're playing against villains with matching stacks, the probability of you running out of chips go up the longer you play. Google Kelly Criterion.

2 - Deepstack poker: Poker at 500BB is very different from 50BB. you may be struggling at the former without knowing it.

I don't necessarily assume there needs to be emotions involved, since you did not give any specific hands or decisions. If your opponents are capped at 100BB, then it could also be just variance, esp if youre playing fast paced cash games, the peaks and troughs are expected to be wide.